# When I access to a key, I want its value and set it in an array. The access is by using strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/dna-pairing
When I access to a key, I want its value and set it array. The way I try to access is with a string. For example: GCG. Therefore, I want to get

```
[["G", "C"], ["C","G"],["G", "C"]]
```

How may I do that?

```
function pairElement(str) {
  let dna = {
         "A": "T",
         "C": "G",
         "T": "A",
         "G": "C"
     }
}

pairElement("GCG");
```

Comment: Hang in there, on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not exactly sure on what you want to do, this does give the output you're expecting.

```js
function pairElement(str) {
    const dna = {
        "A": "T",
        "C": "G",
        "T": "A",
        "G": "C"
    }
    let arr = [];
    for (const key of str){
        arr.push([key, dna[key]])
    }
    return arr;
}

// some input tests
console.log(pairElement("GCG"));
console.log(pairElement("ACTG"));
console.log(pairElement("CCGAT"));
```

Or a one liner:

```js
function pairElement(str) {
    const dna = {
        "A": "T",
        "C": "G",
        "T": "A",
        "G": "C"
    }
    
    return str.split('').map(key => [key, dna[key]])
}

// some input tests
console.log(pairElement("GCG"));
console.log(pairElement("ACTG"));
console.log(pairElement("CCGAT"));
```

Note that you can iterate through string in Javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to:

1) Turn the incoming string into an array using `split` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

2) Turn each element in that array into its array using `map` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and build the pair you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
function pairElement(str) {
  let dna = {
         "A": "T",
         "C": "G",
         "T": "A",
         "G": "C"
     }

  let indi = str.split('');
  var dna_arr = [];
  for(var x=0; x<indi.length; x++) {

    var char = indi[x];
    dna_arr.push(char);
  }

  return dan_arr;



}

pairElement("GCG");
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it solves the question. Your output is `["G", "C", "G"]`, while it should return `[["G", "C"], ["C","G"],["G", "C"]]`. Also, there's a typo at `dan_arr`.